# Нужен совет по верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу услышать ваше экспертное мнение. Как правильно верстать все эти картинки? Я сделал так: синюю картинку с точками внизу сделал через background: url('../img/bg-blue.svg'), а фотки комнат, овал и точки справа внизу через абсолютное позионирование. Или лучше все картинки объединить и сделать как один фон? Как обычно верстают такие картинки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В планшетной версии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как захочется, как будет удобно - так и верстается

Comment: Спасибо большое за ценный совет

Comment: Сделайте два изображения - точки и овал в одной картинке для планшета, точки, овал и фотографии для десктопа - и меняйте url для background-image через @media в зависимости от размера экрана

Comment: А синий фон, через css лучше (border-radius) или как svg экспортировать и потом background-image? Или под овалом вы как раз и имели ввиду синий фон?

Comment: Если вы хотите на десктопе его скомбинировать с фотографиями в одном изображении, то border-radius не подойдет, собирайте все слои фона в одно изображение и экспортируйте (причем PNG будет достаточно)

Comment: мм, понял. Спасибо)